# How do I dump `VM: Mapped File`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

While profiling my iOS app, I noticed a very high memory spike for `VM: Mapped File`, as you can see in this photo:

[image]

I believe this only began happening after uploading some images to AWS and then asynchronously downloading them for display in a UITableView, but I can't confirm that since I started profiling after the app started crashing.

I've searched quite a bit for any information regarding what `VM: Mapped File` is, but I can not figure out how to dump the contents of it, which I've included here:

[image]

In that photo, the top line item with a size of 22MB is `icudt51l.dat - /usr/share/icu`, which has a size of 22MB.  I also can not find information on what that may be.

My suspicion is that it has to do with the image being cached and not being dumped later.

One additional note, if I delete the app from the device, and re-install it, it doesn't go away.

All in all, what is `icudt51l.dat - /usr/share/icu` and/or how can I delete the data in `VM: Mapped File`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapped files are not like regular memory; they can either be on disk only, or in memory and on-disk, and the system will manage that for you.

icudt51l.dat is the localization data for the system; it's what powers NSDateFormatter, NSNumberFormatter, etc... you can't get rid of it.

Basically: that's not really an allocation in the traditional sense and you don't need to worry about it

Comment: Good to know, ok, I'll ignore it for now.

Comment: If you're curious, check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/Articles/MappingFiles.html

Comment: Not only can't you get rid of it, but the system is optimized such that the minimum amount of the file will be paged into physical RAM.    This is done by optimizing the layout of the file to have related data grouped together on ranges of the file that map to individual pages (or rages of pages) in memory.